# Symfony2 Using Entity in Validation Constraint

Tags: php, sql, validation, symfony, entities

I'm trying to validate one unique field using Symfony validation engine. I've created validation constraints and everything works fine but I want to have validated entity (or POST data) in my validator. Here is what it looks for now:

```
<?php
    namespace Webrama\ProductBundle\Validator\Constraints;

    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

    class EanCodeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
    {
        private $entityManager;
        private $translator;
        /**
         * @param EntityManager $entityManager
         */
        public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, TranslatorInterface $translator)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
            $this->translator = $translator;
        }

... some logic ...

        private function isEanUnique($value)
        {
            $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p.id FROM WebramaProductBundle:Product p WHERE p.eanCode = :eanCode AND p.eanCode <> 0");
            $query->setParameter('eanCode', $value);

            $result = $query->execute();

            if(empty($result))
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Method isEanUnique will return false when updating the product becouse it contains ean within itself and it's right. What I need to do to fix?

```
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p.id FROM WebramaProductBundle:Product p WHERE p.eanCode = :eanCode AND p.eanCode <> 0 AND p.id <> :productId");
                $query->setParameter('eanCode', $value);
                        $query->setParameter('id', $this->product->getId());
```

But I don't know how to bring $this->product here... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anwser is the docs... Need to look at the paragraph Class Constraint Validator on the page [How to create custon validation constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html). What I did wrong is that I've tried to enforce type hinting that way:

```
public function validate(Product $product, Constraint $constraint)
{
        ...
}
```

There should be just:

```
public function validate($product, Constraint $constraint)
{
        ...
}
```